# combining two select statements with group by and order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 2 select statements that work and return the info on their own, but was wondering if there was a way to join /  combine them into one report with their own separate rows and columns

```
Select Sum (amount) as PDCGross
From Desk D Left Join
     Master M
     on D.code = M.desk INNER JOIN
     pdc 
     ON m.number = pdc.number
Where teamid = 3
AND active = 1
And onhold is NULL
And deposit >='2020-10-01'
And deposit <= '2020-10-31'
Group by D.Name
Order by desk.Name Desc

Select Sum (amount) as GrossPDCC
FROM Desk D left JOIN
     Master M
     on D.code = M.Desk INNER JOIN
     DebtorCreditCards P 
     ON m.number = P.Number
Where teamid = 3
AND IsActive = 1
And OnHoldDate is NULL
And DepositDate >='2020-10-01'
And DepositDate <= '2020-10-31'
Group by D.Name 
Order by desk.Name Desc
```

The return for the 1st statement

```
PDCPross

2500
1500
1300
```

The result of the 2nd statement is

```
PDCCGross
1500
1300
1000
```

What i am looking for is

```
PDCPross   PDCCGross

2500        1500
1500        1300
1300        1000
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: *combine them into one report with their own separate rows and columns*: rows *or* columns? Please show us the current result of each query, and the result that you are after. Also, it would really help if you qualified each column with the table it belongs to - otherwise, the query is ambiguous about the underlying data structures.

Comment: I'm looking at the `GROUP BY` and I wonder what each of the result's `Name` is. I think you should add `Name` in the `SELECT` of both query, then make them both as sub-query, then join them on that `Name` column. Provided that the `Name` column in both query results return the same, you should be able to show them side-by-side. But, if you don't care about the `Name` and instead wants to order it just as it is, you may have to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign and use that to join the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MySQL v 8.0+ or MariaDB 10.2 +, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

Assign each query with `ROW_NUMBER()` then make both query as sub-query. Join the queries using the `rownum` result and you should be able to see your results side by side. Something like this query example:

```
SELECT A.PDCGross, B.GrossPDCC FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY D.Name DESC) AS rownum, SUM(amount) AS PDCGross
FROM Desk D LEFT JOIN
     MASTER M
     ON D.code = M.desk INNER JOIN
     pdc 
     ON m.number = pdc.number
WHERE teamid = 3
AND active = 1
AND onhold IS NULL
AND deposit >='2020-10-01'
AND deposit <= '2020-10-31'
GROUP BY D.Name
ORDER BY D.Name DESC) A JOIN
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY D.Name DESC) AS rownum, SUM(amount) AS GrossPDCC
FROM Desk D LEFT JOIN
     MASTER M
     ON D.code = M.Desk INNER JOIN
     DebtorCreditCards P 
     ON m.number = P.Number
WHERE teamid = 3
AND IsActive = 1
AND OnHoldDate IS NULL
AND DepositDate >='2020-10-01'
AND DepositDate <= '2020-10-31'
GROUP BY D.Name 
ORDER BY D.Name DESC) B ON A.rownum=B.rownum;
```

Comment: That's great @Knxolon. If it answers your question, would you mind accepting the answer by clicking the check mark? Because if not, your question will still be unsolved and we already have thousands of unsolved questions in SO. Thanks